# Unable to raise ValueError in python using if and else statements

Tags: python

I have a function which takes in a code and checks to see if the code is valid before generating a new password for the user. My code works well but if I want to ensure that a ValueError is raised if the code is not valid, then the error shows up regardless of whether the code is correct or not.

```
def update_password(reset_code, newPassword):
    with open('text.p', 'rb') as file:
        users = pickle.load(file)
        for k, v in users.items():
            code = v.get('password')
            if code == reset_code:
                hashedPassword = hashPassword(newPassword)
                v['password'] = storedPassword
            else:
                raise ValueError("not valid code")
```

any reason why this may be happening?

Comment: Users.items is empty?...would then not get into the loop

Comment: @Ctznkane525 no because my code works otherwise perfectly except when i try to handle errors

Comment: Since the code is very straight forward I dont see any errors in the code, most likely the problem is in the variables, make sure to assert that both passwords are of the same type! `assert type(code) == type(reset_code), "passwords are different types"`

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? Seems `reset_code` isn't defined anywhere that we can see.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a problem with your inputs. For example:

- `reset_code` isn't a hashed password or
- the password that `reset_code` is based on wasn't stripped of trailing spaces or newlines before hashing.

The only bug that I see in your code is that
your `update_password` function doesn't actually *save* the changes in *any* way, since `users` seems to be local to the function.